Shuffle the Array - LeetCode problem. 2 pointers approach fails
I am trying to solve LeetCode problem 1470. Shuffle the Array:

Given the array nums consisting of 2n elements in the form [x1,x2,...,xn,y1,y2,...,yn].
Return the array in the form [x1,y1,x2,y2,...,xn,yn].
Constraints:

1 <= n <= 500
nums.length == 2n
1 <= nums[i] <= 10^3


This is my attempt:
    public int[] shuffle(int[] nums, int n) {
        int temp1 = nums[1];
        int temp2 = 0;
        int i = 1; int j = n;
        while (i < n - 1 && j < nums.length) {
            System.out.println(i + " " + j + " " + temp1 + " " + temp2 + "  " + Arrays.toString(nums));
            temp2 = temp1;
            nums[i] = nums[j];
            i++; j++;
            System.out.println(i + " " + j + " " + temp1 + " " + temp2 + " " + Arrays.toString(nums));
            temp1 = nums[i];
            nums[i] = temp2;
            i++;
            System.out.println(i + " " + j + " " + temp1 + " " + temp2 + " " + Arrays.toString(nums));
        }
        return nums;
    }

I tried this solution, making it O(logN) time. It worked to 50% of the test cases and not for the rest. I guess there is a little bit of modifications required here. I guess no one has used this approach.
Which modifications are needed to make this approach work?

This is a misuse of the term "shuffle".

"making it O(logN) time.": not possible.

Do not tag this as dsa.  The dsa tag is for Digital Signature Algorithm.  What you should tag is the actual computer language you are using.

(@MarkRansom: en.wikipedia on perfect shuffle.)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition is a useful reference for the in-place version of this algorithm. This problem is equivalent to transposing a nx2 column-major matrix (to an 2xn column-major matrix) in-place.

You have to move elements at least n-2 times, which means that the minimum runtime will be no less than O(n).

"It worked to 50% of the test cases and not for the rest." Which 50% of test cases did it not work for?

There are several issues with your attempt:

As the loop exits when i >= n - 1, you'll only have written values in nums[0] up to nums[n] at the most, while nums has elements up to nums[2*n-1].

The logic that you have implemented with temp1 and temp2 implies that for greater input sizes and for even i, the value in nums[i] will be set to that of nums[i-2] for i >= 4. This is correct for when i is 4, but it is no longer correct for when i is greater.


There are many ways you can do it, but it becomes a lot easier if you create a new array for the result and leave the input inaltered. For instance like this:
    public int[] shuffle(int[] nums, int n) {
        int m = 2*n;
        int[] result = new int[m];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            result[i*2] = nums[i];
            result[m - 1 - i*2] = nums[m - 1 - i];
        }
        return result;
    }

Inplace
To do this in place, without allocating another array of the same size, you could follow the cycles. We can imagine the directed graph whose edges connect any index with a second index that has the source value that needs to be moved to the first index. The very first and last element in the input array represent nodes in that graph that have an edge to themselves (they are loops). Other nodes are part of (larger) cycles. We would follow those cycles and rotate the values in each cycle with one step.
To avoid that you follow the same cycle multiple times you'd want to somehow mark an entry as visited. The code challenge you refer to assures that the input values are all strictly positive, so you can use the sign bit for storing that visited mark and remove it again when done.
Here is a possible implementation of that idea:
    public int[] shuffle(int[] nums, int n) {
        int m = 2*n;
        for (int i = 1; i < m - 1; i++) {
            if (nums[i] > 0) { // Not yet moved to its final position
                int temp = nums[i];
                int curr = i;
                int next = (curr % 2) * n + curr / 2;
                while (next != i) { // Follow cycle
                    nums[curr] = -nums[next]; // Move and mark
                    curr = next;
                    next = (curr % 2) * n + curr / 2;
                }
                nums[curr] = -temp;
            }
            nums[i] = -nums[i]; // Remove mark
        }
        return nums;
    }


I tried using another answer array. But I want to do it in place.

You cannot do it in place with just temp1 and temp2. I have added a solution that does it in place without creating another array.

public int[] shuffle(int[] nums, int n) {

   int[] arr = new int[n * 2];

   int index = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       
       arr[index++] = nums[i];
       
       arr[index++] = nums[n + i];
   }

   return arr;
}

